# How can I store values from a text file into an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I´m working with text file reads in Java, and I need to store the content of this text files inside of arrays, and the pass it as references for instance a new Class.

This is the structure of my txt file:

**OXFORD**

Software Engineer, Administracion, Laws

**PRINCETON**

Maths, Economy, Sociology

This is the class who have the structure of the file:

```
public class University {
private String name;
private String[] careers;

public University() {
}

public University(String name, String[] careers) {
    this.name = name;
    this.careers = careers;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String[] getCareers() {
    return careers;
}

public void setCareers(String[] careers) {
    this.careers = careers;
}
```

This is the student class, who have a university and career as attribute from the University class:

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private University university;
private String career;

public Student() {
}

public Student(String name, University university, String career) {
    this.name = name;
    this.university = university;
    this.career = career
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public string setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public University getUniversity(){
    return university;
}

public University setUniversity(University university){
    this.university = university;
}
```

}

As you can see, my careers attribute is an array. I want store the careers and university from the text file in my student careers array. And to do something like this:

Sample input:

```
System.out.println("Greetings student, to what career you wanna set up to");
//here I wanna type the name of the career from the careers list from the text file
```

And then have something like this:

Sample expected output:

```
System.out.println("Congrats new student, your new career is" + career);
```

This is my main method where I am reading the text file and printing it:

```
public static void readFiles() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BufferedReader readBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\sistemaBecas\\src\\ficheros\\Universidad.txt"));
    String docLine;
    ArrayList<String> registerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((docLine = readBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
        registerList.add(docLine);
    }
    String[] arrayDocument = registerList.toArray(new String[0]);        
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayDocument.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Array.get(arrayDocument,i));
        
    }
}
```

How could I do this?

Comment: It is not still clear what is your question. Please post your question/requirements and with the complete code clearly. BTW don't use `Array.get(arrayDocument,i)`  just `arrayDocument[i]`

Comment: Can you show the actual file format exactly as it is? You can enclose the text in `<pre></pre>` tags. Or some people prefer code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String file = "C:\\Users\\Roberto\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\sistemaBecas\\src\\ficheros\\Universidad.txt";
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file));
List<University> universities = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i += 2)
    universities.add(new University(lines.get(i), lines.get(i + 1).split("\\s*,\\s*")));
```